# Create reference lines according to the values in the filter

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, datavisualization.toolkit

I need to visualize the number of teams that spent more than the salary cap allowed. So I want a reference line on behalf of the threshold of each year. However, it seems that the reference line doesn't change when I change the filter value. Here is how I want it to look:
[image]
Here is the data source: https://query.data.world/s/2lej7smnxcvc3gbv342j4chjslvrgo, I set "Season" as the filter so this is the visualization of only one season.

---**EDIT**---:
I need a dashboard that shows the salaries in each season, so the salary cap threshold should be changed when I change the value in the filter "season".

Comment: Thanks for sharing the data file. That helps in clarifying the most of the scene. Can you please also tell how you have calculated/added the filter?

Comment: I made an edition now.

Comment: Y axis is salary, what is x axis, in the above chart?

Comment: see my revised answer and see if it helps.

Comment: "Y axis is salary, what is x axis, in the above chart?" --- Actually I don't care about the x axis, I just let the team sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Further Edit**

see this GIF

[image]

**EDIT** I added a reference line per `pane` with the following options-

[image]

- check scope is per pane
  -check value is average - average

and see it works exactly as desired.

[image]

and

[image]

Now I am not sure what you have depicted on X-axis in your visual/dashboard??

**OLD ANSWER** Though I am not sure how you have added the reference line in the data but you may right click the `season` filter pill in filters shelf and  <kbd>add that to context</kbd>

This will turn the filter action first of all calculations and may be your reference line acts like as desired.

Comment: That makes me feel like my idea is totally unavailable with Tableau. Thanks anyway.

Comment: see that it is changing as filter changes .. pls check

Comment: I found where my question is: I don't even see an option to use Salary Cap as my reference line when y-axis stands for Total Salary.

Comment: See this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NGDinDak_Nf9NDz_uodnPb2y7PyQL3S6/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

My final workaround is to combine two visualizations together and make the markers in the salary cap chart invisible:

1. put the season into the filter cell, and only choose one option:

[image]

2. put team in Columns and SUM(total salary) in Rows, and put another team into shape cell in the Marks card (make sure you assign the logo to the teams respectively):
   [image]
3. put SUM(salary cap) in Rows, that makes you a second viz:
   [image]
4. drag a reference line to your second viz, and here are the params that are supposed to be like:
   [image]
5. so now can you made a line representing the cap, now what you are going to is make this line shown in your first chart, which means you should allow dual axis. Before, you also should convert the markers in the second viz into Polygon, that makes them invisible:
   [image]
6. allow dual axis:
   [image]

One shortage of this solution is that the shape markers will become masked. So to make them recognizable, you better choose some images with transparent backgrounds.

Comment: Instead of following this longer route (workaround) why don't you try my method given in the answer above?  As regards availability of `salary cap` field to create a ref line, just add the field to `details` on `marks card` and then it'll be available under reference line tab/dialog as shown in my answer.  Let me add a gif

Comment: I wish your way were helpful! I just couldn't see an option about salary cap at all when creating reference line!

Comment: see the GIF I have edited.  It'll help you certainly